# What is the Java equivalent to use https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send REST Api

Tags: java, http, post, curl, firebase

I've already tried the following command in Curl to send a notification using the Firebase REST Api and it works:

```
curl -X POST --header "Authorization: key=AIza...iD9wk" --Header "Content-Type: application/json" https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send -d "{\"notification\":{\"title\": \"My title\", \"text\": \"My text\", \"sound\": \"default\"}, \"to\": \"cAhmJfN...bNau9z\"}"
```

Now that I'm trying to do the same in Java, I couldn't find an easy way to do the same and nothing that I've tried triggers the notification in my mobile endpoint.

This is my closest approach:

```
    try {
        HttpURLConnection httpcon = (HttpURLConnection) ((new URL("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send").openConnection()));
        httpcon.setDoOutput(true);
        httpcon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        httpcon.setRequestProperty("Authorization: key", "AIza...iD9wk");
        httpcon.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpcon.connect();
        System.out.println("Connected!");

        byte[] outputBytes = "{\"notification\":{\"title\": \"My title\", \"text\": \"My text\", \"sound\": \"default\"}, \"to\": \"cAhmJfN...bNau9z\"}".getBytes("UTF-8");
        OutputStream os = httpcon.getOutputStream();
        os.write(outputBytes);
        os.close();

        // Reading response
        InputStream input = httpcon.getInputStream();
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input))) {
            for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Http POST request sent!");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But then I get:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1625)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
    at httpclient.test.MyHttpClientPost.sendNotification(MyHttpClientPost.java:131)
    at httpclient.test.MyHttpClientPost.main(MyHttpClientPost.java:26)
```

Comment: Thanks for a well-written question.  A simple issue, but you provided all the details necessary for someone to spot your problem and actually help. More importantly, this question may well help someone else in the future, which is the _whole point_ of StackOverflow, and you have contributed nicely to that.  [Why am I being so effusive? Well-written questions on SO are a rarity as you'll no doubt soon learn]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`401` means unauthorized, so no valid `Authorization` header was sent.

And this line:

```
httpcon.setRequestProperty("Authorization: key", "AIza...iD9wk");
```

Is not equivalent to `-H "Authorization: key=AIza...iD9wk"`. The first argument should be the header name, which is `Authorization`:

```
httpcon.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key=AIza...iD9wk");
```

In conclusion, you misunderstood how HTTP header is formatted. Basically the header name and value are separated by `:` not `=`.

Comment: Well spotted. I read the code twice and still managed to miss that!

Comment: Also make sure you copy the server key from the Firebase console under the tab "Messaging" and not the Web API key like I did initially. They look the same but one gives you a 401 and the other one works ;-)

Comment: @RayHulha Yeah, that's correct. your comment worked :-)

Answer (score 0):

Minimal sample:

```java
public class ConnApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        HttpURLConnection httpcon = (HttpURLConnection) ((new URL("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send").openConnection()));
        httpcon.setDoOutput(true);
        httpcon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        httpcon.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key=!!secret!!");
        httpcon.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpcon.connect();

        byte[] outputBytes = ("{\"to\":\"!!CONFIDENTIAL!!\"," +
                "\"data\":{\"some\":\"thing\"}," +
                "\"notification\":{\"title\":\"Help\",\"body\":\"me\",\"icon\":\"me\",\"sound\":\"default\",\"badge\":\"18\"}," +
                "\"priority\":\"high\"," +
                "\"content_available\":true}").getBytes("UTF-8");
        OutputStream os = httpcon.getOutputStream();
        os.write(outputBytes);
        os.close();

        InputStream input = httpcon.getInputStream();
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input))) {
            for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
    }
}
```